# Junit testing for exception

Tags: junit4

Hello I have a code similar to this and I need to write junit test for it, but I keep getting nullpointeException, can any body write the test for this?

```
 public class myState{
     @Inject
       private StateData stateData;
   public String getAbbreviation(){
       try{
           state selectedState= StateData.getSelectedState().getState();
           formatedAbbrebiation=selectedState.getStline()+""+selectedState.getRegion();

    }
     catch(Exception e){
         formatedAbbrebiation="abbrebiation not available"
    }
     return formatedAbbrebiation;
    }
```

This is what I have tried :

```
StateData stateData=Mockito.mock(StateData.class);
Mockito.when(stateData.getSelectedState().getState()).thenReturn(selectedState)
Mockito.when(selectedState.getStLine())).thenThrow(new Exception());
```

Comment: What have you tried? (And please indent your code so that that others can read it easily).

Comment: StateData stateData=Mockito.mock(StateData.class);
Mockito.when(stateData.getSelectedState().getState()).thenReturn(selectedState)
Mockito.when(selectedState.getStLine())).thenThrow(new Exception());